# "tags":["_dateparsefailure"]," with logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

```
12-Apr-2021 17:12:45.289 FINE [https-jsse-nio2-8443-exec-5] org.apache.catalina.authenticator.FormAuthenticator.doAuthenticate Authentication of 'user1' was successful
```

I am parsing above log message with the below code in logstash and unfortunately getting a **"tags":["_dateparsefailure"],** .

`%{MY_DATE_PATTERN:timestamp}` is an custom pattern as follows `MY_DATE_PATTERN %{MONTHDAY}-%{MONTH}-%{YEAR} %{HOUR}:?%{MINUTE}(?::?%{SECOND})`

I also have checked with https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/ that it parses perfectly fine.

I was wondering that you may be able to see where i am doing wrong.

```
    filter {
                   grok{
              patterns_dir => "/etc/logstash/patterns"
              match => { "message" => "%{MY_DATE_PATTERN:timestamp}\s+%{WORD:severity}\s+\[%{DATA:thread}\]\s+%{NOTSPACE:type_log}\s+(?<action>\w(?:[\w\s]*\w)?)(?:\s+['\[](?<user>[^\]']+))?" }
            }
        # Converting timestamp
                date {
                        locale => "nl"
                        match => ["timestamp", "dd-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss"]
                        timezone => "Europe/Amsterdam"
                        target => "timestampconverted"
                }
ruby {
          code => "event.set('timestamp', (event.get('timestampconverted').to_f*1000).to_i)"
    }
```

The output ( had to remove couple things so that i could post here)

```
user":"user1,"type_log":"org.apache.catalina.authenticator.FormAuthenticator.doAuthenticate","logSource":{"environment,"tags":["_dateparsefailure"],"thread":"https-jsse-nio2-8443-exec-6","action":"Authentication of
```

thanks in advance!

Update

I also tried below and still getting the error

```
date {
                locale => "nl"
                match => ["timestamp", "dd-MMM-YYYY HH:mm:ss.SSS"]
                timezone => "Europe/Amsterdam"
                target => "timestampconverted"
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

It should definitely be "dd-MMM-YYYY HH:mm:ss.SSS" -- you have to consume the entire field. Can you try removing the 'locale => "nl"' option (just for debugging purposes). We are currently in a month where the Dutch and English month abbreviations match. If it starts working then the month abbreviations are not what you think they are. Some locales expect to have a . at the end of the abbreviation. Looking at the [CLDR](https://unicode-org.github.io/cldr-staging/charts/latest/verify/dates/nl.html) charts it definitely appears that locale nl is one of them, so you will have to gsub it in. The CLDR data is [here](https://st.unicode.org/cldr-apps/v#/nl/Gregorian/268fa3faf41b2154), scroll down to "Months - Abbreviated - Formatting". You could try

```
mutate { gsub => [ "timestamp", "(jan|feb|mrt|apr|jun|jul|aug|sep|okt|nov|dec)", "\1." ] }
```

My original suggestion of

```
mutate { gsub => [ "timestamp", "(jan|feb|apr|aug|sept|oct|okt|nov|dec)", "\1." ] }
```

was based on the abbreviations given [here](https://library.princeton.edu/departments/tsd/katmandu/reference/months.html) but that is not what Java uses.

The issue is definitely in the date filter, not the grok. If the grok filter were not parsing the timestamp field then the date filter would be a no-op and would not add the tag.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that custom pattern was causing issue, instead of using it from another location i added to my conf file as regex as following  `(?<logstamp>%{MONTHDAY}-%{MONTH}-%{YEAR} %{HOUR}:%{MINUTE}:%{SECOND})`